# error when running groovy test suite

Tags: eclipse, groovy, junit

created two tests in groovy able to run them indecently as groovy test cases but when I create a test suite and run them like `groovy MyTestSuite.groovy` on cmd line I get the below error:

```
F.F
Time: 0
There were 2 failures:
1) warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in mypack.ArithmeticTest
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1318)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeStaticMethod(InvokerHelper.java:927)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeStaticMethod(InvokerHelper.java:77)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runJUnit3TestSuite(GroovyShell.java:370)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:277)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:502)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:491)
"a.txt" 53L, 3408C
```

The test suite class is as follows

```
package mypack

import junit.framework.TestSuite
import junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter

public class myTestSuite extends TestSuite {
     // Since Eclipse launches tests relative to the project root,
     // declare the relative path to the test scripts for convenience
     private static final String TEST_ROOT = "src/mypack/";
     public static TestSuite suite() throws Exception {
         TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
         GroovyTestSuite gsuite = new GroovyTestSuite();

         suite.addTestSuite(gsuite.compile("/Users/barumugham/Documents/workspace/Groovy/UnitTestGroovy/src/mypack/ArithmeticGroovy.groovy"));
         suite.addTestSuite(gsuite.compile("/Users/barumugham/Documents/workspace/Groovy/UnitTestGroovy/src/mypack/ArrayTest.groovy"));
         return suite;
     }
}
```

ArithmeticGroovy.groovy

```
package mypack

import org.junit.Test
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals

class ArithmeticTest {
    @Test
    void additionIsWorking() {
        assertEquals 4, 2+2
    }

    @Test(expected=ArithmeticException)
    void divideByZero() {
        println 1/0
    }
}
```

when i run it through eclipse i get initializationerror.  I am new to groovy any help is appreciated

Comment: Try to rename the test methods to start with the word test.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy seems to be confused if you confuse (pardon the pun :-) JUnit3 and JUnit4 style. Using `TestSuite` and `addTestSuite` is JUnit3 style and it should be coupled with classes derived from `TestCase` (or ultimately `Test`). Mixing JUnit4 annotation style won't work in this setup as exemplified in [this post](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/GroovyTestSuite-compile-doesn-t-support-annotated-Junit-4-test-td371534.html).

You should select either JUnit3 or JUnit4 style for your tests (where I personally tend to prefer JUnit4).